# The stream or file "/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream:Permission denied

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform

While I work locally, everything works fine. But when I deploy on Google Cloud I have this error

> The stream or file "/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream:Permission denied

I have tried to run this from my terminal. I am using window PC and  Vscode

> chmod -R 775 storage
>
> chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

When I run this, it returns

> chmod is not recognized as internal or external commands, operable program or batch file.

I also tried this method

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 775 storage",
            "chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache",
            "php artisan optimize:clear"
]
```

I don't know how to solve this. I need help

Comment: give permission  777 to storage folder

Comment: How do I give this permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud is a write only filesystem. For directories which need to be written into by the application, you will need to make some modifications.

Please see https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard and make note of steps 1 and 3 under the deploy section, which set the `APP_STORAGE` path to /tmp so that it will be writable.

Answer (score 1):

**just run this first command**

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan clear:cache

php artisan route:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: This won't fix it. It will only fix it temporarily but the error will still remain. It the same using php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: command 2 should be  `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually because your project folder owner is different than your web server's default owner

I don't know which web server you are using but the common web servers are `apache` and `nginx`

For apache and nginx it's usually is www-data so if you are using apache or nginx
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/project/folder`

otherwise you should figure out what is your web server default ownership is.

Edit:

Please note that giving `777` permission is a bad practice and it cause security issues. there is nothing wrong with default permissions of file and folders of laravel.